# Asp.Net .findcontrol() when control doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ran into this two days in a row now. If the label exists, this code works:

```
Label lblQuantity1 = ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQty1f"));
```

If it doesn't, it throws an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there any way to catch this outside of Try/Catch blocks? I would think something like this, but it does not:

```
if ((Label)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQty1f") != null)
{
// do something.
}
```

I've tried casting to objects and seeing if they are null. Doesn't work.

The only thing I have found that works if the label isn't there is to wrap it in Try/Catch blocks. Just seems like there should be a better way than that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) for null safe casting.

```
if(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQty1f") is Label lblQuantity1){
   //safely access lblQuantity1
}
```

Comment: This seems legit and kind of works the way I would expect. I will mark as answer. The only issue is that I'm working on an Asp.Net website, and it defaults to C#5. This is only available in C#7. It appears there isn't just a simple way to change a website to C#7. But I will assume in any other scenario, your code would work. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you may use the "as" keyword. Such as: var lblQuantity1 = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQty1f") as Label. You'll still need to check if ilblQuantity1 is not null so it's not a one line solution, but the "as" keyword will never throw an exception and returns null if the cast is not possible. More here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator